# Nexmo voice call not working

Tags: php, curl, vonage

I have tried to execute the Text to speech API in NEXMO but I an error:

```
$phoneno = "Checkthisout";
$params = "api_key=XXXX&api_secret=XXXXX&to=XXXXX&from=XXXXXX&text=".$phoneno;
$url = 'https://api.nexmo.com/tts/json?'; . http_build_query($params);
$ch = curl_init($url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);  
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
print_r($response);
```

But got the new error `{"status":"2","error_text":"Missing username"}`

Done as per the URL : https://nexmo.github.io/Quickstarts/tts/.

I have checked all their document. I don't see such error text. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: rtfm: http://php.net/httpd_build_query it expects an ARRAY or object. you're passing in a string, which means you're producing NOTHING. your string is already a query, so there's no point in trying to rebuild it as yet another query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Marc mentioned, it expects an array for your parameters, rather than a string

```
 $params = [
     'api_key' => XXXXX,
     'api_secret' => XXXXX,
     'to' => YOUR_NUMBER,
     'from' => NEXMO_NUMBER,
     'text' => 'Checkthisout',
 ];


 $url = 'https://api.nexmo.com/tts/json?' . http_build_query($params);

 $ch = curl_init($url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

You can watch this video for a quick walkthrough: [Text To Speech Quickstart Video](https://vimeo.com/99601185)

*Full discolsure, I work at Nexmo.*

Here is a more detailed documentation on how to implement [Text to Speech](https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/voice-api/text-to-speech)

Comment: Thanks Sidharth Sharma. Its working now. But i was facing this error for more than 5 days. Even nexmo guys are also checking the same. Few hours before only its started to work. .

Comment: Hi @Sidharth Sharma , I'm  struggling on following issue, can you help to clarify? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40543517/nexmo-verify-voice-call-always-disconnect